# How to show keys in a Motobit Multi.Dictionary by the given item value?

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm new to programming so I'm sorry if my question seems dumb. I want to ask if there is any way to return the keys from [`Multi.Dictionary`](http://www.motobit.com/help/asp-dictionary-object/default.htm) when I have the value?

This is my code:

```
Dim myDict
Set myDict= Server.CreateObject("Multi.Dictionary")
myDict.UniqueKeys = False 

'Fill dictionary with some data
myDict("param1") = "value1"
myDict.Add "param2", "value2"
myDict.Add "param2", "value2.2"

'Get dictionary Keys
Keys = myDict.Keys
Items = myDict.Items

For Z = 0 To UBound(Items)
  Response.Write(Keys(Z) & " " & Items(Z) & "<br>")
Next
```

And for now returns

> Subscript out of range: '2'

Which is normal because I loop 3 times while I have only 2 keys.

So is it possible to have a result like this:

```
Param1: "value1"
Param2: "value2" 
Param2: "value2.2"
```

Comment: What do you get when you call `myItem = myDict.Item("param2")` after filling your values? Is the result an array of Items? `typename(myItem)` shows you the type of the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the keys of `myDict` by checking the items multiple or not.

```vb
Dim myDict
Set myDict= Server.CreateObject("Multi.Dictionary")
myDict.UniqueKeys = False 

myDict("param1") = "value1"
myDict.Add "param2", "value2"
myDict.Add "param2", "value2.2"

Dim key, subItem
For Each key In myDict.Keys
    If IsArray(myDict(key)) Then ' item is an array
        For Each subItem In myDict(key)
            Response.Write key & ": " & subItem & "<br>"
        Next
    Else
        Response.Write key & ": " & myDict(key) & "<br>"
    End If
Next
```